# How to use unlock code iphone into my app?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a Swift app with TouchID request when open first viewController. If I enter invalid TouchID some times, This request unlock code of device.

How can I request directly the unlock code device instead TouchID? 
There is a framework, api or code available?

Thanks!